# Disable user input in EditText but allow input programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to disable the option for the user to input text but allow the system to put some text in an EditText?

The onFocus method brings up a calendar, I need that function to be avaialable, so I think the EditText to still be enabled.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The user selects the EditText, a Date/TimeDialog pops up and you select, The text is then put in the EditText. I don't want the user to be able to edit the text after that. I suppose I could find a way to only allow a certain format? So that way, even if they edit the text, it can only be in a date format

Comment: Why not use a clickable TextView?

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fooling around with EditText, why not just use the View that already does what you want: the TextView?

You can define one in XML like so, so it visually responds to touches:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
/>
```